# colorizing UIbuttons

Tags: iphone, uibutton, colorize

Does someone know how to colorize a UIButton (iphone)?  I have a greyscale image with alpha that I want to colorize to various different colors.  Setting things like background color only shade the entire image without respecting the alpha.

Is there a straightforward way to do this, or will I need to subclass UIButton and overload the drawRect method perhaps?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use a one-segment `UISegmentedControl`, which provides access to a tint property. These can behave like a `UIButton` with the right settings, and look a lot like the glass-style that Apple uses for its iPhone apps.